# Convert date time UTC to YYYY-MM

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime-format

need help on Date Time UTC conversion here .
[image]

I have coded below (to remove the UTC timing)

```
SELECT
 
  DISTINCT(delivered_on::date),

  total_amount,

  SUM(total_amount) OVER (ORDER BY delivered_on::date) ,

  COUNT(*)

FROM orders

WHERE delivered_on::date BETWEEN  '2021-01-01' AND  '2021-01-31'

GROUP BY 1,2 ;
```

BUT I need to achieve
2021-01 : cumulative value for entitle Jan'21
For now , im getting the cumulative sum for 2021-01-01 ; 2021-01-02 etc ....
But i want to get the cumulative sum of total 2021-01 (Entire Jan instead)

Comment: You can extract month/year from date and show results accordingly. Something like this - `extract(year from dateColumn) as year;`. I believe, you are trying to send this **2021-01** from a front-end and split in the backend for `SQL` part.

Comment: Thanks ! Ive mange to break the months and year using extract . But how can i achieve cumulative sum ? I cant use "SUM(total_amount) OVER (ORDER BY delivered_on::date)" since my original data for delivered_on date is UTC format.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    to_char((delivered_on::date), 'YYYY-MM'),
    total_amount,
    SUM(total_amount) OVER (ORDER BY delivered_on::date),
    COUNT(*) OVER ()
FROM
    orders
WHERE
    delivered_on::date BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2021-01-31';
```

Comment: Thank you . using to_char((delivered_on::date), 'YYYY-MM') helps with the conversion. Ive used CTE method to achieve the  cumulative total_amount